# Approach to implement a TTL on Django model record

Tags: python, django-models, ttl

I'm looking for the best approach to implement a TTL on Django (1.7+) model records. The aims is to keep only 1 week age records.

Thanks,

Comment: Create a management command that'll run every x minutes and selects+detroys all records that were created >6 days ago?

Comment: Good option ! I will keep it.